# How to solve a IndexOutOfRange made by the user?

Tags: c#, split, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm still new to  programming, so every time i get an exeption i try to rewrite code so it is avoided. However in this case i see no way to work around it.

I have a textbox that the user uses to imput commands. The string(imput) is then split after the first space.

```
        private void tbxMainImput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string commandText = tbxMainImput.Text.ToLower();
            string[] commandTextSplitted = commandText.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ReadTextboxImput(commandTextSplitted);
            tbxMainImput.ResetText();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //anoying beep is removed :)
        }
    }
```

this splitted string commandTextSplitted is being used by a switch method ReadTextboxImput

```
        private void ReadTextboxImput(string[] imput)
    {
        switch (imput[0])
        {
            //some other cases 

            case "attack":
                StartCombat(imput[1]);  //trows exeption if user only types one word
                break;
        }
    }
```

If a player only types one word, imput[1] doesnt exist, and an IndexOutOfRange exeption is cast(as it should). However the exeption seems unavoidable. the player can type one word and press enter...

so ive been trying some things to check for the exeption and then break out of the code but it doesnt seem to work. The msdn website isn't realy beginners friendly, and all i found on stackoverflow where people asking to find where the error came from. witch i know.

So far i have tried:

```
  case "attack":
                if (imput[1] == null) //(imput[1] == system.IndexOutOfRange) doesnt make sense but i had to try
                {
                    rtbOutput.AppendText("Yes yes. Attack nothing...");
                    break;
                }
                StartCombat(imput[1]);
                break;
```

i made a method that uses try and catch that worked, but it just detected the error, i wasn't able to do anything with it(like return a false, or something)

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: You can always check the `.Length` of an array before trying to access something at that index...

Comment: The bigger question is why you are accessing the data like this?  Why not just loop over the array?

Comment: @maccettura this looks like one of those witty MUDs where the game mocks you for not typing the correct target.

Comment: wow. thats so simple i cant believe i thought of that... that wil work yes

Comment: @maccettura i had a feeling of nostalgia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the array length is `> 1` instead of `imput[1] == null`

```
if (imput.Length > 1){
  rtbOutput.AppendText("Yes yes. Attack nothing...");
  break;
}
StartCombat(imput[1]);
break;
```

Comment: the OP said that he tried to check `imput[1] == null`

Comment: that's exactly my point. if `.Length == 0` then `imput[0]` will fail, if `.Length == 1` then `imput[0]` will work but `imput[1]` will fail. You need to check if the `.Length` is greater than 1, not 0

Comment: i tried to check imput[1] becouse i assumed that the  program interpret it as true  wen imput[1] doesnt exist. but it didnt work.  if imput.length = 1 worked though so thanks it solved it